# Changing position of embeded youtube video in CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my first time posting here and don't really know much about web coding or CSS. I'm a CGI artist who is trying to implement a simple feature. I would like to showcase my Demoreel on my website, figured out how to add the video in, but the position is on the far left of the screen. I'm using Artstation web builder, they don't have an option to implement the video visually. I like to place it in the middle of the screen for the website before showcasing projects since its a built website there are lots of coding and hopping can implement the position code in the middle of  without adding in an extra function and such.

I'm using the Firefox Inspector to change the coding when trying to add a position just add a text rather the action on the website.

Any answers regarding to this are very appreciated

Thanks!

```
<div>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ywzukda7WsI" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

[What it looks like now on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EOn4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iframe, add:

```
<iframe  style='display: block; margin: 0 auto;'>
```

And that should work.

I tried it on JSFiddle:
https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/eQwLYe

you can just copy the code from here or the JSFiddle!

Hope I helped you!